# Почему operator++ должен возвращать const T?

Tags: c++, операторы, типы

```
const T T::operator++(int)
{
    T tmp = *this;
    ++(*this);
    return tmp;
}
```

Рассмотрим такой вариант реализации постфиксного оператора инкрементирования. Почему требуется возвращать именно `const T`, а не `T`? Такой вариант реализуется для типа `int`, а нужно ли мне реализовывать этот оператор для своего пользовательского типа аналогично?

Я придерживался негласного правила, что при разработке классов (типов) в случае если непонятно (или еще не сформулировано) требуемое поведение то следует организовать поведение, какое предоставляет `int`. `int` возвращает `const int`. А нужно ли и мне так?

Comment: Исправил, там int должно быть

Comment: @Abyx сейчас  мне скинули, что у Майерса написано про int так, правило 6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет необходимости делать возвращаемый тип константым, чтобы избежать двойного инкремента `++++`. Достаточно объявить оператор инкремента только для lvalue объектов (добавить `&` в сигнатуру):

```
struct T {
    T operator++(int) & { return *this; }
};

int main() {
    T t;

    t++;   // ok    
    t++++; // ошибка
}
```

Comment: Получается, для всех других операторов также потребуется изменять сигнатуру? Т.е. опасен не только вариант i++++, а например, что-то произвольное типа (i++)<some_posfix_operator>

Comment: @Jenssen зависит от того, какую итоговую цель вы ставите. Если хотим избежать постфикных модификаций временных значений, то да.

Comment: Да, пока именно такую. Про move-семантику речи не шло. Но недостаток const я понимал по отношению к rvalue и перемещению. Просто напрочь забыл про такую фичу в сигнатуре. Благодарю)

Answer (score 3):

Постфиксный оператор инкрементирования (оператор декрементирования аналогнично) возвращает `const T`, чтобы предотвратить потенциально некорректное использование некоторых конструкций, т.к. двойное постфиксное инк-/дек- рементирование вида `i++++`.

В силу особенностей реализации этого оператора возвращается прошлое значение объекта, поэтому второй вызов оператора `operator++(int)` изменит значение возвращенной первым оператором копии исходного объекта, а не результата с учетом первого инкрементирования.

Как правило, клиентский код обычно не требует (вообще говоря, не должен) поддержки таких конструкций, как двойное применение постфиксного оператора и одновременное изменение значения, возвращаемого постфиксным оператором, в одной инструкции, поэтому запрет подобной операции через `const T` вполне оправдан. Ошибок избегать это помогает точно.

Comment: Встретил такое в коде, как оказалось, написать так могут.

Comment: А ещё это убивает move-семантику. Подобные советы были мягко говоря сомнительны раньше, а сейчас они ещё стали и вредны, на мой взгляд.

Comment: написать могу все, главное, что бы компилятор переварил. А то, что там UB на UB, то какая разница - главное, что компилируется.

Comment: @KoVadim мне скинули такой код и написали, что вот работает, но только +1 надо в самом конце добавить, чтобы прям совсем работало

Comment: @Jenssen, программист, при написании своих классов, должен руководствоваться простым принципом: класс должен быть написан так, чтобы _случайно_ использовать его неправильно было сложно. Класс не должен защищаться от клинических идиотов и тех, кто специально хочет напакостить.

Comment: @ixSci так это оправданное применение const? Ведь мы и имеем дело с неоправданным применением двух операций в одной строчке

Comment: Я видел неоднократно советы, про то, что нужно делать возвращаемое значение `const`. Не помню, был ли это Майерс, кто это запустили или кто-то другой, но этот совет появился давно. Гораздо раньше, чем появился стандарт 2011 года и семантика перемещений. `const` у возвращаемого значения препятствует  этой самой семантике, и это значит, что объект всегда будет скопирован. Более того, с константой скорее всего даже RVO работать не будет. Я всегда считал этот совет бессмысленным, т.к. никакой очевидной пользы я от него не видел.

Comment: Но тогда, когда он стал ломать семантику перемещений я стал считать его вредным. В C++ есть много мест, когда можно написать неправильно и с этим ничего не сделаешь — нужно проводить ревизию кода. Написать в коде `i++++` может либо идиот, либо кто-то, кто решил это сделать специально. Как я уже сказал, защититься от обоих типов невозможно.

Comment: Чем семантически плох (или даже «сломан»)  двойной инкремент, чтобы запрещать его в корне? Постинкремент возвращает lvalue, а что с ним будут делать дальше — не имеет значения. С таким же успехом можно запрещать взятие адреса от результата `operator*()`.

Comment: @Arhad, постинкремент это rvalue выражение. Если Вы говорите про префиксную форму, то `++++i` с успехом заменяется на `i += 2;`. Второй вариант ясно отражает суть и в нём не рябит в глазах от плюсов. Я не знаю ни одного программиста, у которого первый вариант прошёл бы ревизию кода. Ваши аналогии с взятием адреса мне непонятны, давайте рассматривать конкретный пример.

Answer (score 2):

`const T` в результате функции запрещает неконстантные операции, в частности перемещение (move-семантика).

```
struct X {
  X(X&&);
  const X operator++(int);
  int& operator*();
};

X a;
X b = a++;  // тут будет копирование, а не перемещение
*a++ = 1;  // не скомпилируется
```